# Find parent element in JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added a click event as follows and would like to check if the target has a specific parent.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    // Check here if target has specific parent for example -> #parent
});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You want to check if the document has a parent element?  And why are you binding click to the document?  What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: Do you mean "parent" or "ancestor"?

Comment: I've got a date-picker which should be hidden after you clicked somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't the event's `this` the literal DOM element (not jquery obj)?

`$(document).click(function(event){
   console.log( $(this.parentNode) );
});`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) dom traversal method for this.

according to Pointy's crystal ball, you probably want to do something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('.selector').length > 0) {
  }
});
```

I'm not sure why are you set click handler on document, maybe looking for event delegation and the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: I think you'd want either `.parents(selector)` or `.closest(selector)`, and then check to see if the length of the jQuery object is > 0. *edit* oh unless the question is about the direct parent, then yes.

Comment: @Pointy Yes. Use `$(event.target).parents(selector).length`.

Comment: Works perfect with $(event.target).parents(selector).length. Was exactly what I was looking for! Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I believe this also works..  AFAIK jQuery events use the the literal element instead of a jQuery object when calling events. Basically `this` should be your normal DOM element with normal JavaScript properties.

```
$(document).click(function(event)
{
   let myparent = $(this.parentNode); //jquery obj
   let parent = $(this.parentNode)[0]; //plain DOM obj

   let myself = $(this); //jquery obj;
   let $elf = this; //plain DOM obj
});
```

Note: sometimes using 'self' as a variable is bad/causes conflicts with certain libraries so i used $elf. The $ in $elf is not special; not a jQuery convention or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

     // test parent examples 
    if($parent.hasClass('someclass')) { // do something }

    if($parent.prop('id') == 'someid')) { // do something }

    // or checking if this is a decendant of any parent

    var $closest = $(this).closest('someclass');

    if($closest.length > 0 ) { // do something }

    $closest = $(this).closest('#someid'); 

    if($closest.length > 0 ) { // do something }
});
```

Comment: I think you can also pass a selector to `.parent()`, which would give you a jQuery result with either zero or one element in it..

Comment: You're definitely right you can, I was just trying to give some options and yes that's another one

Answer (score 2):

I have reliably used this in the past:

```
var target = $( event.target )
```

This will give you a reference to the jQuery object for the element that had the event invoked.  You could use this same approach and see if the parent is "#parent", something like this:

```
var target = $( event.target )
if (target.parent().attr('id') == "#parent") {
    //do something
}
```